# Dictionary inside dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I am trying to use a list that is a value for a dictionary key/pair set, and this dictionary is itself a value in a key/pair set in a dictionary. To explain, this is how I initialize it.

```
var dictOfEvents = [Int: [Int: [PFObject]]]()
```

I am trying to add events to the list, with the inner dictionary's key being the day of month and the outer one being the month. For example, an event on May 1 would be:

```
dictOfEvents[5:[1:[ListOfEvents]]
```

Where `ListOfEvents` is an array of `PFObjects`. Before I added the month functionality, and thus the outer dictionary, the way I added new events was:
`    self.dictOfEvents[components.day] = [event]
But now, when I try to extend this with:

```
self.dictOfEvents[components.month]?[components.day]! = [event]
```

It does not work. Any explanation on how to create new event lists and access this double layer dictionary would be greatly appreciated.

(Note: I don't know where to put the ! and the ? in the last piece of code so please excuse me if I made a mistake.)

Comment: What exact error do you get?

Answer (score 1):

U can simple change:

```
self.dictOfEvents[components.month]?[components.day]! = [event]
```

to :

```
self.dictOfEvents[components.month]![components.day]! = [event]
```

Because `Dictionary` has subscript,  `Dictionary?` doesn't have subscript.

if U try add Events to Dictionary. I suggest to use this:

```
var dictOfEvents = [Int: [Int: [PFObject]]]()

var dictOfDayEvents = [Int:[PFObject]]()

dictOfDayEvents.updateValue([PFObject()], forKey: 1)
dictOfEvents.updateValue(dictOfDayEvents, forKey: 5)
```

Comment: This crashes when I try to run it because it `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` I think this is because when trying to add the list of events, the keys for the day and month have not been created yet.

Comment: I suggest U try to defined two 'Dictionary'. And use dictionary.updateValue to add the events. like this:    'var dictOfEvents = [Int: [Int: [PFObject]]]()

var dictOfDayEvents = [Int:[PFObject]]()

dictOfDayEvents.updateValue([PFObject()], forKey: 1)
dictOfEvents.updateValue(dictOfDayEvents, forKey: 5)'

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I think could be a good use of optionals in your case (and should respond to your question):

```
var dic: [Int: [Int: [String]]] = [:]
dic[5] = [1:["Hello", "World"]]

if let list = dic[5]?[1] {
    // your list exist and you can safely use it
    for item in list {
        println(item)
    }
}
```

I just used `String` instead of `PFObject`.

A different approach could be:

```
/*
Define a struct to encapsulate your Month and Day
Make it Hashable so that you can use it as Dictionary key
*/
public struct MonthDay: Hashable {
    let month: Int
    let day: Int
    public var hashValue: Int { return month * 100 + day }
}

public func ==(lhs: MonthDay, rhs: MonthDay) -> Bool {
    return lhs.month == rhs.month && lhs.day == rhs.day
}

var dictOfEvents = [MonthDay :[String]]()
let aMonthAndDay = MonthDay(month: 5, day: 1)

dictOfEvents[aMonthAndDay] = ["Hello", "World"]
if let list = dictOfEvents[aMonthAndDay] {
    // your list exist and you can safely use it
    for item in list {
        println(item)
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this approach and had several problems. Firstly, when initializing, I cannot use the syntax you provided above, `var dic: [Int: [Int: [String]]] = [:]`. The compiler complains that it `Cannot assign to the result of this expression`. In addition, when I leave it the way that I initialized it, and try the second line of your answer, it replaces any previous date/event list dictionaries so only the last one added would be kept.

Comment: Indeed I'd suggest a different approach ... let me edit the answer ;-)

Comment: By the way, beware that in your example you define the inner dictionary having `[PFObject]`, then you use it as `[ListOfEvents]`. This may be the source of your init problems. I used String just as an example since I can't reproduce your Parse environment. Use `PFObject` or a custom class depending on your setting.